# Animate is not clearing queue and keeps doubling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am having an issue with jQuery animate. I have a form and the functionality is on `input` click scroll to the top of the next question. Then at the bottom there is a reset button, however after the reset button is clicked the animate speed doubles. I have tried to add the `.stop(true)` function, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
let scrollHandler = (target) => {
  $('html').stop(true).animate({scrollTop: target}, 500);
}

function next() {
  inputs.on("click", "input", (e) => {
    ...
    scrollHandler($(target).offset().top);
  });
}
```

Comment: How many times is `next()` called?

Comment: every time a question in the form is answered, it works perfectly until the form is reset.

Comment: Try `inputs.off("click").on("click", "input", (e) => { ... });`

Comment: I just figured it out -- because when I click the reset I'm setting `$('#results').addClass('display-none');` any ideas why thats causing the animation to break?

Comment: On resetting the form you need to ensure everything is re-initialised to its original state. That includes removal of event handlers that were dynamically attached during the previous Qs&As. My `inputs.off("click").on("click", "input", (e) => { ... });` suggestion may be only part of the solution.